# Make a marker move depending on the slider position?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, slider, marker, timeline

I have managed to get a working map and I have managed to combine it with the Leaflet timedimension slider. The next thing I have to do is get a moving marker on the map that changes position depending on a scripted path, for example the marker on date X is on some specific coordinates, but on date Y the marker moves towards different scripted position.

I have so far managed to get a marker on the map but I am at loss what I have to do to make it move. I looked at the [various examples](http://apps.socib.es/Leaflet.TimeDimension/examples/) of posted here and the example that seems to be the closest to what I need to achieve is [this](http://apps.socib.es/Leaflet.TimeDimension/examples/example9.html) one, but the code points towards and external .xml file, which I don't know how I have to code it to work and the example code doesn't show what variables does the marker itself have in the .html file.

My question is, is it even possible to get a marker moving using this "timeDimension" slider and if it is, could someone point me towards some example code I could look at?

And a bit unrelated, is my current set up the best thing to use if I want to have a map with a timeline slider that moves around lots of markers over a span of couple of years?

Here is the code I have so far,

```
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
            <title>Home</title>        
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.2.0/leaflet.css" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="leaflet.timedimension.control.css" />
                <style>#map { height: 500px; }</style>
        </head>
    <body>

    <p style="text-align: center;"><strong><span style="font-size: 20px;">Heading test</span></strong></p>

    <!--Map with needed map scripts-->
    <div id="map" style="height: 75%; width: 100%"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.2.0/leaflet.js"></script>
src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/nezasa/iso8601-js-period/master/iso8601.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/socib/Leaflet.TimeDimension/master/dist/leaflet.
    <script type="text/javascript" src="SliderScript.js"></script> //This is the Leaflet slider, just renamed

    <!--Here is a script for map overlay -->

    <!--Markers-->
    <script>
    var Icontest= L.icon({
        iconUrl: 'icons/testicon1.png',
        iconSize:     [40, 25], // size of the icon
        iconAnchor:   [0, 0], // point of the icon which will correspond to marker's location
    });

    L.marker([29, 57], {icon: Icontest},{draggable: true}).addTo(map); //Do I have to add something here to give it coordinates depending on date?
    </script>


    </body>
    </html>
```

This is the SliderScript.js, which is the same thing as the example.js file on [this site](https://github.com/socib/Leaflet.TimeDimension#examples-and-basic-usage).

```
// example.js
var map = L.map('map', {
    zoom: 10,
    center: [38.705, 1.15],
    timeDimension: true,
    timeDimensionOptions: {
        timeInterval: "2014-09-30/2014-10-30",
        period: "PT1H"
    },
    timeDimensionControl: true,
});

var wmsUrl = "http://thredds.socib.es/thredds/wms/observational/hf_radar/hf_radar_ibiza-scb_codarssproc001_aggregation/dep0001_hf-radar-ibiza_scb-codarssproc001_L1_agg.nc"
var wmsLayer = L.tileLayer.wms(wmsUrl, {
    layers: 'sea_water_velocity',
    format: 'image/png',
    transparent: true,
    attribution: 'SOCIB HF RADAR | sea_water_velocity'
});

// Create and add a TimeDimension Layer to the map
var tdWmsLayer = L.timeDimension.layer.wms(wmsLayer);
tdWmsLayer.addTo(map);
```

```js
// example.js
var map = L.map('map', {
  zoom: 10,
  center: [38.705, 1.15],
  timeDimension: true,
  timeDimensionOptions: {
    timeInterval: "2014-09-30/2014-10-30",
    period: "PT1H"
  },
  timeDimensionControl: true,
});

var wmsUrl = "http://thredds.socib.es/thredds/wms/observational/hf_radar/hf_radar_ibiza-scb_codarssproc001_aggregation/dep0001_hf-radar-ibiza_scb-codarssproc001_L1_agg.nc"
var wmsLayer = L.tileLayer.wms(wmsUrl, {
  layers: 'sea_water_velocity',
  format: 'image/png',
  transparent: true,
  attribution: 'SOCIB HF RADAR | sea_water_velocity'
});

// Create and add a TimeDimension Layer to the map
var tdWmsLayer = L.timeDimension.layer.wms(wmsLayer);
tdWmsLayer.addTo(map);
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Leaflet TimeDimension Demo</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.2.0/leaflet.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/socib/Leaflet.TimeDimension/master/dist/leaflet.timedimension.control.min.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="map" style="height: 100%; width: 100%"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.2.0/leaflet.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/nezasa/iso8601-js-period/master/iso8601.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/socib/Leaflet.TimeDimension/master/dist/leaflet.timedimension.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="example.js"></script>
  <!--Markers-->
  <script>
    var Icontest = L.icon({
      iconUrl: 'icons/testicon1.png',
      iconSize: [40, 25], // size of the icon
      iconAnchor: [0, 0], // point of the icon which will correspond to marker's location
    });

    L.marker([29, 57], {
      icon: Icontest
    }, {
      draggable: true
    }).addTo(map); //Do I have to add something here to give it coordinates depending on date?
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Would it be possible to create a [mcve] using scripts from a CDN

Comment: I have posted the entirety of the code I have so far, including a marker for a test. I don't know anything on how to make the marker move depending on the slider, I hoped someone would point me towards some example I could look at and use.

Comment: Your scripts are not available. Please fill in the full path of `<script type="text/javascript" src="iso8601.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="leaflet.timedimension.min.js"></script>` for example

Comment: Sorry for that. I just added those two script paths so that they point towards the scripts on the internet and the code for the last one named SliderScript.js is now under the main .html code I posted.

Comment: If you click the `[<>]` snippet editor you can make a [mcve]

Comment: Ok I tried to add the snipped as you said but I don't understand how can I add an external .js file in the Javascript pane so that the HTML part can read it, sorry. This is the first time I tried to use it. I added the .js code in the Javascript pane.